# Allow improving suggested edits on the mobile website

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, mobile-web

On the normal website, once you have submitted a suggested edit, you can just click [edit] again to improve it. This does not seem to be possible on the mobile version of the website. *Especially given that there's no 'preview' option on mobile*, it sometimes happens that the formatting can be improved, like here (expletive has been grayed out):

[image]

It shouldn't be hard to show an [edit] link between the [share] and [flag] links, like the normal site.

Comment: This is not an actual answer to your request, but another way to look at this is like so: maybe it's intentional, because that way you avoid situations like (1) submit edit (2) 1st review (3) re-edit (4) 2nd review ... The "problem" (IMO ...) with this sequence is that both reviewers did not review the very same revision of what was suggested. And as per my intentional above: maybe it's simply not implemented yet on the "normal website". PS: you think it's worth reworking my comment to a followup-question?

Comment: IIRC that situation has already been discussed before, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: OK, that sounds like "fair enough" to make it a new (real) question, for those who don't use IIRC ... like me, merci!

Comment: Thanks @ShadowWizard for finding the duplicate. SE showed me over 20 possible duplicate questions while asking this one, but not the one you found.

Comment: Probably because it was missing suggested edits tag, added now. :)