# Allowing users to submit suggested edits more than once

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

I have noticed that if a user submitted their suggested edits on Stack Exchange, they cannot alter the suggestions afterwards. In other to solve this problem, we could allow every user to submit their suggested edits not more than three times per day. In this way, Stack Exchange will not receive too much suggested edits and users can make some changes in case they found something wrong in their suggestions. Overall, the aforementioned policy would improve the usability of Stack Exchange.

Comment: What makes you think "they cannot alter the suggestions afterwards"? That's just not true, as the answer explains.

Comment: Welcome to Meta Stack Exchange, Dominic! Since this is your first post here, I just want to make sure you're aware of something: [voting on feature requests signals disagreement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) rather than perceived quality and usefulness. The downvotes on your question do not mean it is a bad question. It just means the downvoters disagree with it.

Comment: Thank you @Pikachu the Purple Wizard. I understand how the feature works now.

Answer (score 10):

> I have noticed that if a user submitted their suggested edits on Stack Exchange, they cannot alter the suggestions afterwards.

Actually, they can. They just need to click the 'edit' link again, and they'll be taken to the version they submitted and can make improvement. The only place where this doesn't work is the [mobile version of the website](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295269/295232), but the workaround here is to switch to the responsive design with the 'full site' link in the footer.